# Hide Other Shipping (if free shipping active) plus also hide free shipping if active for a customer Group

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3, vqmod

Opencart Version 2.3.0.2 - currently using Vqmod (below) to hide other shipping when free shipping is active. I am looking to adapt it to also hide free shipping for a particular Customer group = '2" (i.e. Wholesale customers will not see\be allowed free shipping).

```
<file path="catalog/model/extension/shipping/*.php">
<operation error="skip">
<search><![CDATA[if ($status) {]]></search>
<add position="before"><![CDATA[
if (get_class($this)!='ModelExtensionShippingFree') {
if (($this->config->get('free_status') == 1) && (float)$this->cart->getTotal() >= $this->config->get('free_total')) {
$status = false;
}
}
]]></add>
```

Comment: you can use this free extension : https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=33939&filter_member=Codingrays%20Pvt%20Lmt

Comment: @ K.B.  the code I posted effectively does what the free extension does, I am looking for a way for it just to apply to default customers (Group Id = 1) not wholesale customers (Group Id = 2)

Comment: for the customer group  after your condition regarding shipping add this condition: `if ($this->session->data['customer_group_id'] == 1) { $status = true; } else { $status = false; }`

Comment: @K.B. unfortunately in this case your suggestion does not work

Comment: @K.B. thanks u pointed me in the right direction managed to get there using elseif

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a lot of experience with opencart, but AFAIK you don't need to use `vqmod` for opencart v2.3 or above. Plus, it's performance bottelneck and unpredictable.

The `index` method of class `ControllerCheckoutShippingMethod` [ `catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_method.php` ] is responsible for generating all the shipping methods and putting them all inside the session. Opencart allows us to place an event right after this index method call and modify the final output.

[Create a module](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/developer/module/) with the below content inside the `install` method and whatever else you wanna put it in there:

```
<?php
// admin/controller/extensions/module/mymodule.php
public function install() {
 $this->load->model('extension/event');
 $this->model_extension_event->addEvent(
      'my_custom_module',
      'catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_method/after', // add event after shipping_method index call
      'extension/module/mymodule/eventAfterSM' // your module file (mymodule.php) with eventAfterSM method in it
 );
}

// catalog/controller/extension/module/mymodule.php
public function eventAfterSM() {
  // this method will be called right after `ControllerCheckoutShippingMethod`->`index`
  // copy and paste the entire index method code in here and modify accordingly
  // and finally set the modified data
  $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/payment_method', $data));
}
```

Comment: interesting - though if possible would prefer to use vqmod